# C# web service calls works only the first time

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I'm making an application to automate the process of call a webservice functions.
It works the first time and do the first function what I call successfull but at the next calls says me:

> InternalServerError

The sample code I have is the following:

```
soapRequest = new XDocument(
                            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                            new XElement(ns + "Envelope",
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soapenv", ns),
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + prefijoText, myns),
                                new XElement(ns + "Header"),
                                    new XElement(ns + "Body",
                                        new XElement(myns + nombreFuncionText,
                                            new XElement(myns + parametroAEnviar, parametroFuncText))
                                )
                            ));
```

This code builts the xml that I have to send to the web service at the correct format.
But it works only on the first iteration, the first call and the next calls shows InternalServerError as I commented before.

Also, If needed I put below my code of doing the call to the web service via HttpClient:

```
try
                        {
                            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
                            {
                                // Se pasa la url del servicio web en la request
                                var request = new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = new Uri(urlBBDDText), Method = HttpMethod.Post };
                                request.Content = new StringContent(soapRequest.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

                                request.Headers.Clear();
                                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
                                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
                                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapActionText);

                                // Nombre de usuario y contraseña se le pasan al httpclient codificados. Opciones: Basic, NTLM, Digest
                                var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usuarioText + ":" + passText);
                                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

                                HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

And I when I enter to the event view to see what's happen it shows me this message:

> Parameter parametro1 in method FuncionParam in service Prueba is null!

It says that **parametro1** is null, but when I built the xml to send, parametro1 has value:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:pru="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Prueba:FuncionParam">
    <soapenv:Header />
        <soapenv:Body>
            <pru:FuncionParam>
                <pru:parametro1>WSTEST06</pru:parametro1>
            </pru:FuncionParam>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that parametro1 contains WSTEST06 as value, how the event viewer says that is null? How I could fix the InternalServerError making the call to the web service?
Any help would be very appreciated :)

**EDIT: Ok, It works! I fixed it, the xml that I hand-crafted wasn't the same as the SOAP request accepts and that gave me InternalServerError several times.**

For your information: The SOAP request accepts this sample xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pru="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Prueba">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pru:FuncionParam>
         <pru:parametro1>ValueOfParameter</pru:parametro1>
      </pru:FuncionParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I passed the incorrect xml format as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pru="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Prueba:FuncionParam">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pru:FuncionParam>
         <pru:parametro1>?</pru:parametro1>
      </pru:FuncionParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> xmlns:pru="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Prueba:FuncionParam"

There is the problem, the urn was incorrect, after "Prueba" was the name of the function that Im calling and the correct string is until "Prueba" word.

Comment: Any particular reason for hand-crafting a SOAP request?

Comment: I thought that I need to do it due to I can't access the .wsdl file and I needed to download the xml from the url and then hand-craft the SOAP request with the information grab from it.